# Jekyll Post.Url not working

Tags: jekyll

New to Jekyll. I'm putting together a list view of post categories(review).. The loop works fine, spits out the image, post etc.. but when I try to add the link {{ p.url }} it does not work.. Suggestions?

```
{% for reviews in site.categories.review %}
    <tr>
      <th>{{reviews.title}}</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
      <td style="width: 33%;"><img style="width: 200px;" src="{{ site.baseurl }}/images/posts/{{reviews.banner_image}}"></td>
      <td><strong>{{reviews.category}}</strong>
          <ul>
            <a href="{{ post_url }}"><li>Key Point #1</li></a>
            <li>Key Point #1</li>
            <li>Key Point #1</li>
            <li>Key Point #1</li>
            <li>{{ reviews.tags }}</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Learn More..." name="Learn More..." class="button"></div>
          </td>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `{{ reviews.url }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of : {{ post_url }}
David Recommended: {{ reviews.url }}

It worked.